# Launch default Smart Hub app on Samsung Tizen from web application

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app

After some research I came to conclusion that this app has id `org.volt.apps`, but starting it via `tizen.application.launch` or `tizen.application.launchAppControl` gets me on default app screen, not one that is used by Smart Hub.

Is there any way to launch `org.volt.apps` with exact same result as if I pressed SmartHub button on my remote?

Answer (score 2):

Please notice that usage of *launch/launchAppControl* API is limited for your own applications only. Related remark says about it [here](https://docs.tizen.org/application/web/api/5.5/device_api/tv/tizen/application.html#ApplicationManager::launch):

> Remark: Use this method for proper case only, for example to launch
>   your own app. Do not abuse the API for other app(s) launch without
>   business consideration.

Using other applications can cause legal issues of your application.

I sugest:

1. Contact [Seller Office](https://developer.samsung.com/tv/distribute/seller-office/support/11-qa) and ask about details of using built-in Samsung TV application *"org.volt.apps"*. I think that your question could be then handled by legal-matters specialists and provide you valid answer.
2. Probably need to make an agreement with application owner, depending on previous step results.
3. Ask application's owner how to reach your goal (to start the application in desired state). Application probably need to have proper data provided to start in non-default state. It is application dependent, so application owner could only provide details.

Answer (score 0):

This guide is from Samsung 1:1 Q&A support to open App details page on App Store (smarthub) from your current app.

```
function launchSmartHub() {

var appName = 'com.samsung.tv.store';

var subMenu = 'detail';

var widgetID = 'xxxxx'; //Target app id on App Store, 13 numbers of App ID

var callerID = 'yyyyy'; //Current app ID. 13 numbers of App ID

var appControl = new window.tizen.ApplicationControl('http://tizen.org/appcontrol/operation/view', null, null, null, [

new window.tizen.ApplicationControlData("Sub_Menu", [subMenu]),

new window.tizen.ApplicationControlData("widget_id", [widgetID]),

new window.tizen.ApplicationControlData("caller_id", [callerID])

]);



window.tizen.application.launchAppControl(appControl, appName, function onLaunchSuccess() {

console.error("Launched Successfully---------------------");

}, function onLaunchError(e) {

console.error(e, "Error on AppControl Launch");

}, {

onsuccess: function() {

console.error("Reply Here");

}

});


/*
URL to app store is different per each year;
•2016 org.volt.apps
•2017 org.volt.apps
•2018 com.samsung.tv.store
•2019 com.samsung.tv.store
•2020 com.samsung.tv.store
•2021 com.samsung.tv.store
*/
```